# Selecting a date using custom calenderview

Tags: java, android

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHemE.png)

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH2Ba.png)

I want a custom calenderview like these images and when we tap on any date it should show the selected date. I have done a lot research on this but I could not find any way to make a calenderview like this. please help me out, Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this library - https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

It's got exactly what you need.

Comment: in 'Calendar in Dialogs' the calendarview is horizontally scrolling but I want vertical scrolling and when we select any date than dialog should be dismissed but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimePicker library, more details here :
[DateTimePicker](https://github.com/flavienlaurent/datetimepicker)